# MODX, transfer configuration data (ClientConfig package) to a file php

Tags: configuration, modx-revolution

I have a script that sends an email. Can the data specified in this script be taken from the configuration fields?

Below is the php code where you need to specify the mail settings:

```
$mail->Host = 'eushared10.twinservers.net';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '';
$mail->Password = '';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->setFrom('PV Koval System');
$mail->addAddress('prudkyi87@gmail.com');
$mail->isHTML(true);
```

Configuration screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu0Ui.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with CC settings like with other system settings using `getOption()` f.e.

```
$mail->Host = $modx->getOption('host_setting');
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $modx->getOption('login_setting');
$mail->Password = $modx->getOption('password_setting');
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->setFrom($modx->getOption('from_setting'));
$mail->addAddress($modx->getOption('email_setting'));
$mail->isHTML(true);
```

This is if your code is inside snippet/plugin, otherwise for external script you should add next code ot the beginning of your file :

```
define('MODX_API_MODE', true);
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/index.php';
$modx->getService('error','error.modError');
$modx->setLogLevel(modX::LOG_LEVEL_INFO);
$modx->setLogTarget(XPDO_CLI_MODE ? 'ECHO' : 'HTML');
/*...*/
$mail->Host = $modx->getOption('host_setting');
/*...*/
```

Comment: Thanks, but....  I tried it, it doesn't work....
Perhaps you need the php files to be in a specific directory, for example, core/elements.

Now the php file from which I am trying to access is in the "assets" directory

Comment: Yes, it was about snippet call, as for external file please add at the beginning of your script code - see above in my original answer.

Comment: Thank you. Everything works as it should!

Comment: @SerhiiLinework I'm glad to hear that! Please mark reply as solution if it is helpful.